# How to make a selectInput with a choice list following an inputdata

Tags: r, shiny

my idea is take all unique values from a column when the user upload a file, after that my choices at selectinput will change to those unique values.

There is my  ui.R code:

```
`library(shinythemes)
 shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = "mystyle.css",
  titlePanel("Pruebas"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file2", HTML("<table><tr><td><strong>Choose your VCF file</strong></td>
<td>
<div class='help-tip'>
    <p>Upload your VCF file with which you will work.</p>
                                          </div></td></tr>
                                          </table>
                                          "),
                  multiple = TRUE,
                  accept = c("text/csv",
                             "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                             ".vcf")),
      selectInput("filter", h3("Choose your filter"),
                   choices = list("Chr 1" = 1, "Chr 2" = 2,
                                   "Chr 3" = 3),selected = 1)`
```

So my idea is with the "file2" do a filter and get those unique values using that:

```
`df <- read.csv(input$file2$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", quote = '"', skip = 56)
x <- unique(df[,1]
x <- levels(x)`
```

Then if we do x[1], we will get the first unique element, then i want to make a choice list where the options are all the element on the list "x".

I tried something at server.R with:

```
`        outVar <- reactive({
  inFile <- input$file2

  if (is.null(inFile))
    return(NULL)
  dff <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", quote = '"', skip = 56)
  y <- unique(dff[,1])
  y <- levels(y)
  y
})
observe({
  updateSelectInput(session, "mychrlist",
                    choices = outVar()
  )})`
```

And then at ui.R:

```
`selectInput("select2", HTML("<table><tr><td><strong>Chromosome</strong></td>
<td>
<div class='help-tip'>
    <p>Filter by chromosome to focus one chromosome insted all of them.</p>
                                          </div></td></tr>
                                          </table>
                                          "), 
                              choices = ("mychrlist")),`
```

But the choice list stay at "mychrlist" and i wanted something like Chr0, Chr1, Chr2 etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Like in the example from the [documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.5/fileInput.html), add a `NULL` check to your reader logic for `input$file2`.

When the app starts, the input has a default `NULL` value until it is set for the first time. So you are initially giving `read.csv` a `NULL` reference to read from.

Comment: I just added it but the "choices" are only "mychrlist" and the result that i want is a list to choose between all the uniques chromosomes like: Chr0, Chr1, Chr2 etc.

Comment: Ok then, those things always take some time figuring them out.